# WebStorm/JetBrains: cannot recognize es6 syntax in a .vue file

Tags: syntax, ecmascript-6, webstorm, vue.js, jetbrains-ide

I'm using vue framework in Webstorm, with ES6 syntax.

I've installed the `vue-for-idea` plugin, and everything goes well if I use pure ES5 syntax.

But it seemed the ES6 part of the code is not recognized yet, and was highlighted warned:

This piece of code for example:

```
<script>
import { DeUser } from '../api/resource';

export default{

.....

ready() {
  // Warned by: The expression statement is not assignment in this code
  DeUser.get().then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp);
  });
},
</script>
```

I run my project perfectly and get resp correctly, but WebStorm shows me the tips the expression statement is not assignment, how can I resolve it?

Comment: Not sure what other syntax Vue uses, but have you tried registering .vue files as HTML under File Types in Preferences?

Comment: yes,but it also show me the tips

Comment: WebStorm version used?

Comment: @gbhlwm 1) Please use `@username` otherwise user is not notified on new comments 2) The support for ES6 syntax in **ordinary/plain** `<script>` tags [was added](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16444) only in **2016.2** version -- you can [try EAP built here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/06/webstorm-2016-2-eap-162-844/)

Answer (score 3):

Finally got a simple solution, in your `.vue` file, just add the `lang="babel"` as an attribute in your `<script>` tag:

```
<template>
  <!-- markup content -->
</template>

<script lang="babel">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add lang="babel" or type="text/ecmascript-6" to  tag.

```
<script lang="babel">
</script>
```

or:

```
<script type="text/ecmascript-6">
</script>
```

In addition, Visual Studio Code has some good plugin of vue, you can have a try.

[vue plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJBsj.png)